# line or string?

Tags: python, string, list

I've used different ways for INPUT these days using python.

```
f=open('txt','r')
for line in f:.....


f=open ('txt','r').readlines()
for line in f:...



samtoolsin = subprocess.Popen(["/share/bin/samtools/samtools","view",bamfile],
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)

f = samtoolsin.stdout
for line in f:.....




f= commands.output('zcat '+ file)
for line in f:.....
```

For all the situations above, is f a list, or just string?
According to my experience, seems 1,2,3 are all list, but the 4th is string. But I don't know why.thx

Comment: For 1 and 3, neither. A file (or file-like object) is iterable, but it's not a list. "According to my experience" is generally a bad guideline. Read the documentation for each; they'll tell you their return types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

- 1 and 3: [file object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)
- 2: list
- 4: string

#### Long Answer (mainly links to docs):

```
f=open('txt','r')
```

- [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) returns a [File Object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects). It is iterable, but is neither a string nor a list.

---

```
f=open ('txt','r').readlines()
```

- [file.readlines()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) returns a list

---

```
samtoolsin = subprocess.Popen(..., stderr=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
f = samtoolsin.stdout
```

- [subprocess.Popen.stdout](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) will be either a File Object (as in your case) or `None`.

---

```
f= commands.output('zcat '+ file)
```

- [commands.getoutput()](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#commands.getoutput) returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over a file object f is actually an iterator that returns one line each time it's called. This has lots of advantages because if you do .readlines() you store the entire list in memory, and also have to read the whole thing before processing.